# how to add rounded corner scrollbar for IE and edge

Tags: css

i have following css for rounded corner srollbar which works [perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1tju.png) for chrome browser

```
.scrollbar {
    height: 600px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 18px 30px 18px 30px;
}

#SearchPanel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

#SearchPanel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

#SearchPanel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #646468;
}
```

but the same css its not getting applied for IE and edge.

i also tried with this

```
@media (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example:

You can try this in your `CSS`:

```
@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
#header { background-color: pink; }
}
```

Comment: this also not working.  is webkit-scrollbar-track support IE or edge